# problem with changing the color and size of same text in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

This is my code for building a text editor. Everything works fine but the thing is when I change the font size of the selected text and after it want to change the color of the same text, it changes the size of the text back to the default. I want to know how can I fix this issue.

Some people suggested defining a hashmap where we save each character that entered in the textarea and save it with its style. But I couldn't figure it out.

#### sample.FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.collections.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<?import org.fxmisc.richtext.InlineCssTextArea?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" 
        prefHeight="564.0" prefWidth="790.0" 
        xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
        fx:controller="sample.Controller">
  <center>
    <InlineCssTextArea  fx:id="textArea" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" 
        onKeyTyped="#handleTextAreaAction">
      <BorderPane.margin>
        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
      </BorderPane.margin>
      <padding>
        <Insets bottom="1.0" left="1.0" right="1.0" top="1.0" />
      </padding>
    </InlineCssTextArea>
  </center>
  <top>
    <HBox BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
      <children>
        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#UploadButtonClicked" 
            text="Upload">
          <HBox.margin>
            <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
          </HBox.margin>
        </Button>
        <ComboBox fx:id="familyComboBox" onAction="#familyOnAction" 
            promptText="Font Theme">
          <HBox.margin>
            <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
          </HBox.margin>
          <items>
            <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
              <String fx:value="Arial" />
              <String fx:value="Times new Roman" />
              <String fx:value="Calibri"/>
            </FXCollections>
          </items>
        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox fx:id="sizeComboBox" layoutX="62.0" layoutY="10.0" 
             onAction="#sizeOnAction" promptText="Font Size">
          <HBox.margin>
            <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
          </HBox.margin>
          <items>
            <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
              <String fx:value="11" />
              <String fx:value="12" />
              <String fx:value="14" />
              <String fx:value="18" />
              <String fx:value="24" />
            </FXCollections>
          </items>
        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox fx:id="ColorBoxColor" layoutX="180.0" layoutY="12.0" 
            onAction="#colorOnAction" promptText="Font Color">
          <HBox.margin>
            <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
          </HBox.margin>
          <items>
            <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
              <String fx:value="Red" />
              <String fx:value="Black" />
              <String fx:value="Green" />
              <String fx:value="Blue" />
            </FXCollections>
          </items>
        </ComboBox>
        <Button fx:id="bold" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" 
            mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#boldOnAction" text="Bold">
          <HBox.margin>
            <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
          </HBox.margin>
        </Button>
        <Button fx:id="italic" layoutX="487.0" layoutY="10.0" 
             mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#italicOnAction" text="Italic">
          <HBox.margin>
            <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
          </HBox.margin>
        </Button>
      </children>
    </HBox>
  </top>
</BorderPane>
```

`Controller.java`:

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.IndexRange;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.text.FontPosture;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import org.fxmisc.richtext.InlineCssTextArea; 
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.URL;    
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Controller {
    Map<Integer,String> list = new HashMap<>();

    @FXML private ComboBox ColorBoxColor;
    @FXML private InlineCssTextArea textArea ;
    @FXML private ComboBox sizeComboBox;
    @FXML private ComboBox familyComboBox;

    String fontType ;
    int fontSize;

    CharacterStyle style = new CharacterStyle();
    @FXML
    public void handleTextAreaAction(KeyEvent key) {          

    }

    public void italicOnAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    public void boldOnAction(ActionEvent event) {
    }
    @FXML
    public void colorOnAction(ActionEvent event) {

        try {
            int last = (textArea.getText().lastIndexOf(textArea.getSelectedText()))+textArea.getSelectedText().length();
            int start = last - textArea.getSelectedText().length();

            if (ColorBoxColor.getValue().equals("Red")) {
                textArea.setStyle(start,last,"-fx-fill: "+style.getColor("red"));
            }
            else if (ColorBoxColor.getValue().equals("Black")){
                textArea.setStyle(start,last,"-fx-fill: "+style.getColor("black"));
            }
            else if (ColorBoxColor.getValue().equals("Green")) {
                textArea.setStyle(start,last,"-fx-fill: " +style.getColor("green"));
            }else{
                textArea.setStyle(start,last,"-fx-fill: "+ style.getColor("blue"));
            }
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
    @FXML
    public void sizeOnAction(ActionEvent event) {

        try {
            int last = (textArea.getText().lastIndexOf(textArea.getSelectedText()))+textArea.getSelectedText().length();
            int start = last - textArea.getSelectedText().length();

            if (sizeComboBox.getValue().equals("11"))
                fontSize = style.getSize(11);
            else if (sizeComboBox.getValue().equals("12"))
                fontSize = style.getSize(12);
            else if (sizeComboBox.getValue().equals("14"))
                fontSize = style.getSize(14);
            else if (sizeComboBox.getValue().equals("16"))
                fontSize = style.getSize(16);
            else if (sizeComboBox.getValue().equals("18"))
                fontSize = style.getSize(18);
            else
                fontSize = style.getSize(24);

            textArea.setStyle(start,last,"-fx-font-size: " + style.getSize(fontSize));

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            System.out.println("Error");   
        }
    }

    public void familyOnAction(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            int last = (textArea.getText().lastIndexOf(textArea.getSelectedText()))+textArea.getSelectedText().length();
            int start = last - textArea.getSelectedText().length();

            if (familyComboBox.getValue().equals("Times New Roman")) {
                fontType = style.getFont("Times New Roman");
            } else if(familyComboBox.getValue().equals("Arial")) {
                fontType = style.getFont("Arial");
            }
            else
                fontType = style.getFont(("Calibri"));

            textArea.setStyle(start,last,"-fx-font-family: " +fontType);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }

    public void UploadButtonClicked(ActionEvent event) {
    }  
}
```

I want to find out what did I miss so it wont get back to default when I apply more than one style on a specific text.

Comment: Can you check that the strings you compose to set the style actually end with ";"? This seems the convention in the documentation of the org.fxmisc.richtext.

Comment: the this is it change the color when I select the color I want but the thing is it return the size to default one. so the semi colon does not affected.

Comment: "I want to find out what did I miss so it wont get back to default when I apply more than one style on a specific text" please post [mcve] reproducing the error.

Comment: There is a similar problem reported in https://stackoverflow.com/q/29631663/3088138, https://stackoverflow.com/q/21385117/3088138, apparently `setStyle` overwrites the full style. You would need to get the existing style, change just the relevant setting in the text string and then set the style with this changed string. Or use variables in the CSS as in the answer there, so that changing the variable value automatically changes the more complex style.